# Vector images imported from SVG images not being recognised in ImageView

Tags: java, android, svg

**The SVG that I was attempting to import was not correctly formatted, this lead to the xml for the vecto image not being correctly formatted either Try the following samples [here](https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/) as these are all correctly formatted SVGs.**

I am attempting to add a SVG image into a ImageView but i keep on getting an error every time I try to call its @drawable/ value. The file seems to be in the right location since when I use a PNg image it works, but it does not get recognised when its an SVG image.

The XML to add the image is :

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/statusImage"
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="391dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/statusText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_temp" />
```

and the location of the image file is:

[image]

I have tried to modify the Gradle file so that it contains:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

But that does not seem to solve the issue I'm having.

The error log seems to print that :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: sc17dpc.individualproject, PID: 3467
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class ImageView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class ImageView
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable sc17dpc.individualproject:drawable/ic_temp with resource ID #0x7f07006d
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_temp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07006d
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1166)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:917)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:1074)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1013)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:630)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:783)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at sc17dpc.individualproject.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:23)
```

and points to my class HomeFragment on the line:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
```

Any help is appreciated since the solutions that I've followed currently have not solved the problem.

*********EDIT*********

The SVG file is imported using the "New -> Vector Asset" built in feature in Android Studio and by using a local file.

The image file looks like:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="640dp"
    android:height="640dp"
    android:viewportWidth="640"
    android:viewportHeight="640">
  <path
```

followed by a load of information about the image path.

I have attempted to change app:srcCompat to android:src and this still gives the same error as before.

Comment: how do you import svg file to your project?

Comment: Show us the contents of your ic_temp file.  It should be a VectorDrawable file. It **cannot** be an SVG file.

Comment: The SVG file is imported using the "New -> Vector Asset" built in feature in Android Studio and by using a local file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been sumarised at the top of the article. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try again?

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_temp"
```

You can't use viewportHeight and viewportWidth as 640

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="640dp"
android:height="640dp">
```

[Source VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable)

Comment: Im afraid that still gives me the same error as before